# My twitter bootstrap grid layout using col-md-4 isn't working

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

I was following the railscast 328 "Twitter bootstrap basics" and I couldn't ever get the column stuff to show up in the right hand.

http://railscasts.com/episodes/328-twitter-bootstrap-basics

I read further and realized he was showing an older version of rails so I started tried to get stuff to work with the new twitter bootstrap in rails... and i swore one load it worked, the stuff was to the right in a column, now every other one its under the other col-md stuff and cannot figure out why, I wonder if its how I did the navbar that broke it?  Maybe a second set of eyes but I just don't see why it is not working... here is what I have:

```
<body>

  <!-- Static navbar -->
      <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
              <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
              <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title Here</a>
          </div>
          <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
              <li class="active"><%= link_to "Home", controller: "home", action: "index" %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Groups", groups_path %></li>
              <li><%= link_to "Providers", providers_path %></li>
              <li class="dropdown">
                <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                  <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                  <li class="divider"></li>
                  <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                  <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                  <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                </ul>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
              <li class="active"><a href="./">Default <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
              <li><a href="../navbar-fixed-top/">Fixed top</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
      </nav>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row"> 
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-8"> <%= yield %> </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-4">
      <!-- should be a column on right it isnt working -->
      <h3> Welcome to the Cool App 1</h3>

    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Remove the `yield` and hardcode something inside and see if it works. I guess yield had an extra div closing and the `.col-md-4` went outside `.row`

Comment: i am a putz, that was a good idea.  It worked..but then i added the yield back and it works again.  I think that is the code gods telling me to hang it up for the night.

Comment: Is there a dynamic content inside yield which changes everytime on refresh? When you get the issue again, inspect and see if the `col-md-4` is inside `.row`.

Comment: actually on another PC i develop on I took the yield out and it still has that column under neath the other one.  Both are linux mint machines, do I somehow maybe have the wrong bootstrap version?   I wish I could check versions of stuff, maybe check the version of the gem?

Comment: check this blog post about complicated grid layouts...http://www.respocert.com/bootstrap/bootstrap-grid-system-step-by-step-understanding